# How to exclude directory from source in an SBT Play Framework 2.3 project

Tags: java, build, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have multiple Play Framework 2.3.8 projects that share a common set of models and other library files from a different repository.  This other "shared" repo is symlinked into the `app` directories of each of the projects during development, and copied there before deploy.

I want to have all of the unit tests associated with this set of shared libraries in the shared repo, so that they get executed regardless of which project they're being compiled in.  However, because these files are all then buried in the app directory, which is defined as sources by default in build.sbt, the project won't compile because the package is defined from the viewpoint of the test directory.

The structure roughly looks like this:

```
app/
  controllers/
  shared -> ../../shared
test/
  shared -> ../app/shared/test
```

Is there a way in my build.sbt to tell it to ignore the `test` directory inside of `app/shared`?  Or, if someone has a better suggestion for how to structure this, any ideas are welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: I feel like I'm close with:

    `excludeFilter in unmanagedSources := "*Test.java"`

but now I'm getting:

    `[error] (compile:compile) java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: /Users/<.....>/app/shared/test/util/TypeConverterTest.java`

Comment: The above error seems related to the PostCompile step, as it's compiling successfully, then throwing that when `at play.PlayCommands$$anonfun$PostCompile$1$$anonfun$6.apply(PlayCommands.scala:84)`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, of excluding `test`:

```
excludeFilter in (Compile, unmanagedSources) := {
  val testDir = ((sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "shared" / "test").getCanonicalPath
  HidderFileFilter | SimpleFileFilter(_.getCanonicalPath.startsWith(testDir))
}
```

To answer your second question, a better way to structure this is to use project refs:

```
lazy val shared = ProjectRef(file("../shared"), "shared-name")

lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(shared)
```

In this setup, `../shared` is a stand alone build with it's own `build.sbt` that you can publish etc, and `shared-name` is the name (set by `name := "shared-name"` of the project in that build).

An even better way would be to have the `shared` project be the root project, and `myProject` (and other projects that depend on it) be sub projects in the same build.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response James!  However, when trying to start activator, I get an error saying `value | is not a member of object sbt.HiddenFileFilter`, and Intellij is additionally claiming that `SimpleFileFilter` cannot be resolved.  (Also, I think you have a typo in HiddenFileFilter)

Comment: We started development with this setup on Play 2.0 when it didn't support subprojects, but I'm sure it should probably at least be set up the first way you suggest...

Comment: Hmm, I updated it to `HiddenFileFilter || new SimpleFileFilter(_.getCanonicalPath.startsWith(testDir))`, but when compiling I still get the error `[error] (compile:compile) java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: /Users/<.....>/app/shared/test/util/TypeConverterTest.java`

Comment: @James Roper, Can you help me out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755358/sbt-project-model-classes-as-form-object-in-play-framework-returns-always-null

Answer (score 1):

My solutions for problems like this is to define a "unit test JAR", i.e. a JAR that is like `junit.jar` in that you can add it to your project as test dependency and that it contains support code for tests.

To use the support code, you need to write a test which extends the unit test support code or kicks off some kind of runner that runs the test in the support JAR.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I'll probably use this as a fallback in case I can't get another solution to work.